# Express Route not registering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express. I am having difficulties in making routes using express().Router .

Here is my index.js (npm main file):

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const loaders = require('./loaders')
const moment = require('moment')

// Constants
const port = 7052

async function startServer() {
    const app = express()

    await loaders.loader(app)

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`listening on ${port} port`)
    })

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        let remoteAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress
        remoteAddress = remoteAddress.replace("::ffff:", "")

        const logNumber = moment().format('YYYYMMDDhhmmss')
        req.headers.lognumber = logNumber
        reqoriginalUrl = req.originalUrl
        vendorlocation = '/update/vendorlocation'

        if (reqoriginalUrl.indexOf(vendorlocation) < 0) {
            let Logtxt = remoteAddress + " Case - "+ logNumber + " - " + req.method + " - " + req.originalUrl + " ==> " + JSON.stringify(req.body)
            if(req.method != 'OPTIONS'){
                console.log(Logtxt)
            }
        }

        var route, routes = [];

        app._router.stack.forEach(function(middleware){
            if(middleware.route){ // routes registered directly on the app
                routes.push(middleware.route);
            } else if(middleware.name === 'router'){ // router middleware 
                middleware.handle.stack.forEach(function(handler){
                    route = handler.route;
                    route && routes.push(route);
                });
            }
        });

        console.log(routes)

        next()
    })

    require('./routes')(app)

    const connection = require('./providers/DBProvider')
    app.set('sql', connection)

    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        console.log('here')
        const errs = new Error('Not Found')
        err['status'] = 404
        next(errs)
    })

    let haltOnTimedout = (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.timedout) next()
    }
    app.use(haltOnTimedout)
}

startServer()
```

This is my routes.js file:

```
const UserRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes')
const Middleware = require('./middleware/middleware')

module.exports = (app) => {
    const userRoutes = UserRoutes.userRoute

    app.use('/v1/user/', Middleware.checkToken, userRoutes)
}
```

This is my userRoutes.js file:

```
const Router = require('express').Router()
const Validator = require('../validations/UserValidations')
const Controller = require('../controllers/UserController')

Router.post('/login', Validator.login, Controller.login)

module.exports = {
    userRoute: Router
}
```

This is my userValidatios.js file:

```
const { body, check } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = {
  login: () => {
    return [
      check('email', 'Email is Mandatory!').not().isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
      check('password', 'Password is Mandatory when Signin in!').not().isEmpty()
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my UserController.js file:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const crypto = require('crypto')

module.exports = {
    login: async (req, res) => {
        console.log('in controller')
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(402).send(reqResponse.errorResponse(402))
        }

        let data = req.body
        let params = req.params
        let query = req.query

        console.log('request data', data)
        res.status(201).send({
            status: true,
            message: 'good!',
            data: data,
        })
    },
}
```

When hit `http://localhost:7052/v1/user/login` from postman,
this is what console shows:

```
::1 Case - 20201007093759 - POST - /v1/user/login ==> {"email":"vishwas@seekmi.com","password":"123456"}
[
  Route {
    path: '/login',
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
    methods: { post: true }
  }
]
```

While I have logged `req.body` in my controller method.

Comment: You should define your routes before starting the server with `app.listen`

Comment: Done. But still not able to get to my controller.

Comment: Why are you messing with `app._router.stack`?  It is not necessary to use this to define routes on your server.  What is the point of that loop?

Comment: I want to check which routes are registered.

Comment: Is there a call to next in your userValidations,js

Comment: @SachinNayak I have made edits in question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like this:

```
Router.post('/login', Validator.login, Controller.login)
```

need to be this:

```
Router.post('/login', Validator.login(), Controller.login)
```

`Validate.login` by itself just returns an array so that's not actually a middleware function.  When Express calls it as part of a middleware function, it just returns an array which Express ignores (the return value from calling a middleware function is not used).  Instead, you need to call it immediately to get the array of middleware functions and then pass that array of middleware functions to Express when you register your middleware.  Express will then call each function in the array as middleware and the validator can then do its work.

FYI, there's no particular reason that `Validator.login` needs to be a function that has to get called to get the array.  It could just be the array directly and then you wouldn't need to call it first.  That's just a coding style choice.

Answer (score 1):

In the `userRoutes.js`  Try Like this,

```
const Router = require('express').Router()
const Validator = require('../validations/UserValidations')
const Controller = require('../controllers/UserController')

Router.route('/login').post([Validator.login, Controller.login]);

module.exports = Router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your validator should have some different specs. In your case, I would suggest that you modify UserRoutes.js :

> Router.post('/login', Validator.login(), Controller.login)

**Note**: Observe the () as a part of the second parameter. This will result in a call to the login uservalidator, and thus the array of validators will be passed as middleware to the pipeline.

This is based on the usage pattern mentioned in the express-validator middleware. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/